# swift 3 error : Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, swift3

Just converted a project to Swift 3 and cant figure out the following error.

```
public func currencyString(_ decimals: Int) -> String {

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = decimals
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(self))!
}
```

the return line is showing an error "Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads"

Any idea what needs to change to resolve this

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
public func currencyString(_ decimals: Int) -> String {

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = decimals
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: decimals))!
}
```

Because if you check [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber) you will get predefined init like:

```
public init(value: Int)
```

Comment: Thanks, needed NSNumber(value: self)

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Comment: Great that this works but without an explanation of why it solves the problem it's not very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

To clarify the confusion as to what the error is,

NSNumber is calling `NSNumber.init( value: X )` method to instantiate a NSNumber object.

**"Argument labels '`(_:)`' do not match any available overloads"**

The code produces the error because NSNumber is not a type rather it is a class with members. `"NSNumber(...)"` instantiates a class object to contain the '***value'*** of `(1.0 / 1.29)`.

**This is not a type conversion or cast like in C/C++.** where you are trying to ***cast*** the type to allow the compiler to do its job.

```
float y = 1.3;
int x = int( y );
```

NSNumber is not a type like `int, float, char`

The error comes into play because there are several ways to call `NSNumber.init( value: type )`

Swift is requiring that you specifically say that you want the 'value' member of the NSNumber to contain the value x.

```
  let localRate = NSNumber( 1.0 / 1.29)
  var y = NSNumber( 0 )
  var b = NSNumber( false )



   let localRate = NSNumber(value: 1.0 / 1.29)
   var y = NSNumber( value: 0 )
   var b = NSNumber( value: false )
```

The confusion might be coming into play because this works.

```
w = String( "4" )
```

The class String does not require the argument label, while NSNumber does require an argument label of 'value:'

*Perhaps this is due to how IOS treats NSNumber as coming from legacy?*

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "backButton")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "backButton")
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Don't get what? Editing, answer quality, ..?

Comment: Please explain how the example provided helps to answer the concern in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3.0.1

```
public func currencyString(_ decimals: Int) -> String {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .default
    let priceString = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:product.introPrice))
    return priceString!
}
```

Difference between syntex

```
// Old code
formatter.string(from: NSNumber(product.introPrice))!

// swift 3.0.1
formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:product.introPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer shows how `NSNumber` initializer should be called correctly, it is good to know that there is no reason to convert Swift numbers to `NSNumber` if we use the `string(for:)` method instead of `string(from:)`.

```
return formatter.string(for: self)!
```