# Swift 3 error: "Argument labels '(named:_:,_:,)' do not match any available overloads" while trying to load an array of UIImage into a UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, xcode8

I'm having an issue trying to load an array of images into a UITableView with a prototype cell in another view controller.

I didn't seem to get an answer from [swift 3 error : Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443953/swift-3-error-argument-labels-do-not-match-any-available-overloads) as I am pretty new and couldn't derive the explanation from the answers.

I am receiving the error in the title from:

```
let portraitsOfHeroes:[UIImage] = UIImage(named: "picture1", "picture2", "picture3")
```

while trying to make an array of images with (portraitsOfHeroes):

```
import UIKit

class NewHeroVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

let listOfHeroes:[String] = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
let portraitsOfHeroes:[UIImage] = UIImage(named: "picture1", "picture2", "picture3")
```

and use them through (cell.newHeroPortrait.image):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "heroCell", for: indexPath) as! NewHeroCell
    cell.newHeroName.text = listOfHeroes[indexPath.row]
    cell.newHeroPortrait.image = portraitsOfHeroes[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

What's the reason it's returning the error on my array?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
let portraitsOfHeroes:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "picture1"), UIImage(named: "picture2"), UIImage(named: "picture3")
```

Comment: That worked thank you so much! What was wrong with my array line?

Edit: Hey having to repeat the bit "UIImage(named: "...")" over and over seems tedious.  Is there a better way to construct that line of code?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `UIImage(named:)` can only take one name and it only returns a single image. You need to create separate `UIImage` instances for each image name.

If you want to avoid typing the `UIImage(named:)` part over and over, you can use `flatMap` and the array of file image names:

```
let portraitsOfHeroes:[UIImage] = ["picture1", "picture2", "picture3"].flatMap { UIImage(named: $0) }
```

The benefit of this approach is that it deals with missing images. If `UIImage(named:)` returns a `nil` image for a given image name, that image simply doesn't appear in the array.

Comment: Very useful, much better than entering the   UIImage(named:) redundantly.