# Argument labels '(_:, fromDate:, toDate:, options:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

```
        var toTimePVC: UIDatePicker!
        var fromPVC: UIDatePicker!
        let unit:NSCalendar.Unit = .minute
        let cal = NSCalendar.current
        let minutesComponents = cal.components(unit, fromDate:fromPVC.date, toDate:  toTimePVC.date, options: NSCalendar.Options.MatchStrictly)
        let startingTime = cal.components(unit, fromDate: date, toDate: fromPVC.date, options: NSCalendar.Options.MatchStrictly
```

I am getting this error in Swift 4. How to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443953/swift-3-error-argument-labels-do-not-match-any-available-overloads

Comment: Where is the remaining code.? At least show what is the argument value?

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1407925-components). Better consider adopting `Calendar` than `NSCalendar` in Swift.

Comment: Don't use `NSCalendar` in Swift. Use `Calendar`.

Comment: I have used Calender still it is not working.

Comment: Use `Calendar`. Avoid `NSStuff` when possible and use `Stuff` if available. Comment that line, and then rewrite it char by char letting XCode completion help you to find the equivalent and the correct syntax.

Comment: The signature of the method is wrong. It's always worth it to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Swift 3, the Objective-C method `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` is imported as [`components(_:from:to:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1407925-components) in Swift.

But rewriting your code following the signature above, I get this error:

```
let minutesComponents = cal.components(unit, from: fromPVC.date, to: toTimePVC.date, options: NSCalendar.Options.matchStrictly)
```

> ```
> 'components(_:from:to:options:)' has been renamed to 'dateComponents(_:from:to:)'
> ```

---

Use `Calendar` instead of `NSCalendar` and [`Calendar.dateComponents(_:from:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292887-datecomponents):

```
    let components: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.minute]
    let cal = Calendar.current
    let minutesComponents = cal.dateComponents(components, from: fromPVC.date, to: toTimePVC.date)
```